# Generating PDF from JSON Object , images are not displaying

Tags: java, html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a requirement to generate PDF document from JSON Objects. Am doing the following

1. Converting JSON to XML
2. Converting XML to HTML using XSL
3. Generating PDF from HTML

While converting XML to HTML using XSL, i have images in XSL with `<img>` tag which is not parsing and coming in the PDF which am generating. Apart from that image rest of the contents are coming fine in that PDF.

Am having those images in my `src/main/resource` directory in my webapp.

How can i include images also in the XSL to generate in PDF too.

Am having those image in my web application resource directory.

Please find my XSL :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/receipt">
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table style="width: 100%;">
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: center; width: 25%;">
                    <img src="img/Open.png" style="width: 50%;" />
                </td>
                </td>
                <td style="font-size: 12px; vertical-align: top; width: 25%;">

                    46-68 Kléber<br/>
                    Tél: +1 <br/>
                    Fax: +1
                </td>
                <td style="font-size: 12px; vertical-align: top; width: 25%;">
                    725 € <br />

                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center; width: 25%;">Date <xsl:value-of select="date" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please find my XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<receipt>
    <incoterm_term>DAP</incoterm_term>
    <oracle_number>5019346</oracle_number>
    <address_name>FKR KREFELD REGELTECHNIK KG</address_name>
</receipt>
```

Please find the java code which am using to convert JSON to PDF

```
public String getOrderAcknowledgementPDF(JSONObject obj) throws IOException, DocumentException {

    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    StringBuilder xml = new StringBuilder();
    String xmlheader = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";

    xml.append(xmlheader);
    xml.append("\n");
    xml.append("<receipt>");
    xml.append(XML.toString(obj));
    xml.append("</receipt>");

    Transformer transformer;
    try {
        transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(new StreamSource(new File(xslPath)));
    } catch (TransformerConfigurationException | TransformerFactoryConfigurationError e1) {
        throw ExceptionUtils.handle((Exception) e1);
    }

    DOMResult result = new DOMResult();

    try {
        transformer.transform(new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"))), result);
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        throw ExceptionUtils.handle(e);
    }

    ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
    try {
        renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("C:/WINDOWS/FONTS/ARIAL.TTF", true);
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        throw ExceptionUtils.handle(e);
    }

    Document resultDoc = (Document) result.getNode();
    renderer.setDocument(resultDoc, "");
    renderer.layout();

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    renderer.createPDF(baos);
    baos.close();
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(baos.toByteArray());

}
```

Comment: Please edit the question and add the input XML.

Comment: @AniketV - I have added my XML also..

Comment: If the image is displaying fine in the HTML that is generated, then this is not really a problem with XSLT, but with the process that converts the HTML to PDF. You probably need to rephrase your question to explain more how you are doing the conversion of HTML to PDF. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to convert your XML to HTML and PDF? You can generate PDFs directly from XML with XSL-FO. This would most likely also solve your problems with your images.

Comment: @Ferestes - am not using XSL-FO package., am using plain XSL version 1.0